# POW like server for Lua web development (super simple / no config)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lua, webserver, rack-pow

Is there is simple **[POW](http://pow.cx/)** like web development environment for **[Lua](http://lua.org)**?

The idea being, with a single command (no configuration) - you have a self contained web development environment for Lua up and running in seconds.

*(In case you're not aware, Pow is a Ruby on Rails environment that quickly allows you to begin web development in a self contain directory)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Pow doesn't serve a language, it makes a connection to a rack-compatible web framework. So if you used a Lua web framework - like, say, [Kepler](http://www.keplerproject.org/) or [Orbit](http://www.keplerproject.org/en/Orbit), you could write a [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/)-compatible loader for it, and then it should Just Work with pow.

(The pow devs are already working on figuring out how to do this in a more generic way; see https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/120 for more details.)

Answer (score 2):

There's Xavante, which is a development server written in Lua for the Kepler project. Some people also run it in production, although personally I wouldn't do that, since it's socket mechanism is based on select(2) and doesn't scale terribly well.